# Palindrome returns false in function C++

Tags: c++, string

For some reason, in the following recursive function,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int n, m, p = 0;
char A[510][510];

void DFS(int x, int y, string s){
    if(x == n && y == m){
        if (s == string(s.rbegin(), s.rend())) p++;
    } else {
        if(x < n) DFS(x+1, y, s + string(1, A[x][y]));
        if(y < m) DFS(x, y+1, s + string(1, A[x][y]));
    }
}

int main() {
    // your code goes here

    cin>>n>>m;
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j<m; j++)
            cin>>A[i][j];

    string s = "";
    DFS(0, 0, "");
    cout<<p<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

never increments **p**, that is the **string s** is never a palindrome though in my program,s is indeed a palindrome quite few number of times. But it still returns false in the following line

```
if (s == string(s.rbegin(), s.rend()))
```

Is it because of function ? 
Some of the values s takes are: **aaa, aba, aabaa, abbb, bab**

I have made sure there is no preceding and following spaces in the **s**

P.S: I have checked, **x == n && y == m** does come true.

Example Input:

```
3 4
aaab
baaa 
abba
```

Outputs **0**. Palindromes: **aaaaaa, abaaba, aaaaaa**

Comment: Perhaps you should use a debugger and see what the result of `string(s.rbegin(), s.rend())` is and whether the string is actually equal tot he contents of `s`.

Comment: I have done that. And the result was both s and reverse one has the same value. @CaptainObvlious. I even printed the strings like this: s:aba: d:aba:

Comment: If the comparison fails either the strings aren't the same _or_ you have a bug elsewhere in your code that's having an impact on the comparison or other related code.

Comment: Bug elsewhere in the code? How would that effect this part of the code? And could it be because i am passing the string as an argument? Could that be the reason somehow? @CaptainObvlious

Comment: In a case like this, try putting the intermediate value, in this case the reversed string, into a temp variable and printing that together with s, to see that first of all the comparison is reached, and to see what exactly the values are.

Comment: @hyde Tried that. Tried doing a lot of thing, storing value of s in another string a, and then matching up with a and a's reverse. Storing the reverse value in another string. Printing all the intermediate strings.

Comment: I can't even check the line you say is failing because it doesn't compile for me.

Comment: @JeffS http://ideone.com/wZc7rl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in these lines:

```
    if(x < n) DFS(x+1, y, s + string(1, A[x][y]));
    if(y < m) DFS(x, y+1, s + string(1, A[x][y]));
```

In the first line, it may be that `y==m`, and on 2nd line, it may be that `x==n`.

These value is then used to access `A`, outside the bounds of valid input. Now those values are initialized to zero, which results in `'\0'` char being added to the string, which is completely valid with `std::string`, it can contain that character, it does not mark end of the string, like in C string! Even when printing, they are just skipped, instead of ending the print of that string there.

To verify, try printing the length of the string in addition to string contents before you reverse it. You will notice the length is always 7, even though printed string is shorter. And then, when you reverse the string with those zero bytes, they get reversed too, so you end up with reversed string having zero bytes at the beginning (skipped and invisible when printed), while original has them at the end, so they are different.

Now I'll leave actually fixing your algorithm for you, but crude solution would be remove the tailing zeroes *before* reversing the string.

Comment: Thank You for the explanation !